# Haskell & JSON - dealing with null

Tags: json, haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

I'm fairly new to Haskell and have been using Wreq to interact with a JSON API. I'm having an issue trying to edit a JSON response before submitting it back to the API. I think the problem lies with an undefined Bool.

In short, the Wreq response body in ByteString form looks like:

```
"{\"a\":1, \"b\":null}"
```

b is actually a boolean but the API response leaves it as null. I'm trying to use Lens functionality to edit it but with no success. The issue is easily reproduced in GHCI:

```
> import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB
> bstr = "{\"a\":1, \"b\":null}" :: LB.ByteString
> print $ bstr & key "b" . _Bool .~ True
"{\"a\":1,\"b\":null}"
```

Nothing is changed. What am I missing here?

Comment: ? B is obviously not a boolean, because if it was a boolean then it would be true or false.

Comment: Maybe you should treat the value as a `Maybe Bool` rather than a `Bool`, using something like `fromMaybe b` to either extract a boolean value or replace `null` with a default value `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `_Bool` prism only works when the value at key `"b"` is either `True` or `False`, not when it's `Null`.  In essence, you're trying to change the type of the value from `Null` to `Bool`.

Probably, you want to use the `_Primitive` prism instead.  Something like:

```hs
bstr & key "b" . _Primitive .~ BoolPrim True
```

Keep in mind that this will change *any* value, not just `Bool`s or `Null`s into `True`.  If you want to be a little more selective, you could do something like:

```hs
bstr & key "b" . _Primitive %~ (\b -> case b of
  NullPrim -> BoolPrim True
  _ -> b)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's spot on. I guess I need to dive further in to prisms!